# active rendering on JPanels

Tags: java, swing, rendering, graphics2d

I am trying to make a PacMan game clone. I am aware that for custom painting I should override the `paint()` or `paintComponent()` method. But I want to control all the painting by myself so I don't want the AWT's `repaint()` call to `paint()`, for that, I set `IgnoreRepaint()` for both the frame and `JPanel`. The call to get `JPanel`'s `graphicsContext` returns the graphics object, but it ain't showing any result just a white background.

The main class is like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args){

        JFrame frame=new JFrame("PacMan...");
        Board board=new Board();
        frame.getContentPane().add(board,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setIgnoreRepaint(true);
        board.init();
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }
```

.... and the `Board` class extends `JPanel` whose `graphicsContext` I want to use, the class is like this. `readMaze()` reads the maze map and assigns the values to `maze[][]`

```
public Board(){

        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        readMaze();
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(rows*SIZE,columns*SIZE));
        setIgnoreRepaint(true);
    }

    public void init(){
        createMaze();
    }




    public void createMaze(){

        Graphics graphics=getGraphics();
        draw(graphics);
        graphics.dispose();


    }

    public void draw(Graphics graphics){
        for(int i=0;i<columns;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<rows;j++){
                //System.out.println(maze[i][j]);
                switch(maze[i][j]){
                case 'd':{
                    graphics.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
                    graphics.fillRect((i)*SIZE+SIZE/2, (j)*SIZE+SIZE/2, 5, 5);
                }
                break;
                }
                // morre cases...

            }
        }
    }
```

I am just a beginner so please ignore my bad coding style.  Thanks.

Comment: For gaming and animation you may be happier with JavaFX.  Search net for "JavaFX Pacman".  You can still learn Java, graphics and all, but the tools and approach with JavaFX will get you to your goal faster.

Comment: getGraphics returns the last graphics context used to paint the component, which probably hasn't been painted yet be use you've disable the painting process so it doesn't know int needs to be updated. Perhaps you should consider implementing your double buffering approach. Basically have a "active" buffer which is painted in the paintComponent method and in your game loop, you would switch between the offscreen and active buffer each time y update it, so event if Swing does a paint in between your updates, it's only painting the active buffer

Comment: Also, don't dispose of a Graphics context you didn't create, this could be disabling any future painting. You also need to be sure you're not doing anything that might be blocking the EDT